# Do not show image when use User Control In Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control in my project (asp.net) that have an image. It has below code:

```html
 <%@ Control Language="C#" ClassName="Header" %>
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        <img alt="The Night Owl" 
            src="../Images/bookshelf.jpg" 
            width="800" height="110"/>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel id="menuPanel" runat="server">
        <a href="../Default.aspx">Home</a> |
        <a href="../Titles.aspx">Titles</a> |
        <a href="../Authors.aspx">Authors</a> |
        <a href="../Publishers.aspx">Publishers</a>
    </asp:Panel>
```

I can see image in user control but when i use it in my default.aspx page, it do not show image. my default.aspx code is:

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register src="~/controls/Header.ascx" tagname="Header" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>The Night Owl</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


    <uc1:Header ID="Header1" runat="server" />
    <h1><span lang="en-us">Home Page</span></h1>
    <asp:Panel runat="server">
        Welcome to The Night Owl, where all of 
        your technical needs are met!
    </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of `src="../Images/bookshelf.jpg"` in the `default.aspx` page it can not be load, user controls dont reference images well unless you specify the whole path or the page and user control are in the same folder,
Your `UC` is in a sub folder but Default page not,
Change the `src` something like `~/subf/subf1/img.jpg`.

If that page and `UC` are in a same folder your `src` will work.
But if they are not in the same folder you should change `src` as I mentioned.

There is something about [Path](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142013/There-is-something-about-Paths-for-Asp-net-beginne).

Comment: In the user control I change source of image to src="../ReusableCode/Images/bookshelf.jpg" , then image don't show in user control but shown in Default.aspx page. How do to display picture in both file?
Although I have used the method proposed by Suprabhat.  But I still have this problem. I also read page Path that you mention above.

Comment: @Piroozman Do you use `<asp:Image/>`  and did you test by `~`,e.g. I have a `UC` in a sub folder which have an `<asp:Image/>` so this is works nice for me `<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Styles/images/background.png" />` it also works for `img`.

Comment: asp:Image  or img runat="server" ?